# React-router v6. How is matchPath supposed to work now

Tags: react-router, react-router-dom

In version 5 I could perform check this way https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/matchPath

```js
import { matchPath } from "react-router";

const match = matchPath("/users/123", {
  path: "/users/:id",
  exact: true,
  strict: false
});
```

In version 6 I get an error on the screen. How should this work now?
[error: pathname.match is not a function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHnix.png)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It looks like in `react-router-dom@6` the order of the arguments passed was inverted.

[matchPath](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/utils/match-path)

> ```
> declare function matchPath<
>   ParamKey extends string = string
> >(
>   pattern: PathPattern | string,
>   pathname: string
> ): PathMatch<ParamKey> | null;
>
> interface PathMatch<ParamKey extends string = string> {
>   params: Params<ParamKey>;
>   pathname: string;
>   pattern: PathPattern;
> }
>
> interface PathPattern {
>   path: string;
>   caseSensitive?: boolean;
>   end?: boolean;
> }
> ```

`pattern` is the first argument, `pathname` is the second.

You've passed `pathname` then `pattern`:

```
const match = matchPath("/users/123", {
  path: "/users/:id",
  exact: true,
  strict: false
});
```

To resolve swap the order of arguments passed to `matchPath`:

```
const match = matchPath(
  { path: "/users/:id" },
  "/users/123",
);
```

Comment: Did I understand correctly that "exact" is the "end" in "PathPattern"?

Comment: @VadimP. Possibly, in RRDv6 all route paths are *always* exactly matched. There isn't a direct 1-to-1 relationship between `Route` component props from v5 and v6. Unfortunately the current v6 docs don't explain this `end` property at all, but if I had to guess it may serve a similar/analogous purpose. Could dig into the source to see how it's used.

Comment: @VadimP. Stumbled across this `end` prop later when reading through the docs in the [`NavLink`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#navlink), but if you scroll down a ways from there you'll see "If the `end` prop is used, it will ensure this component isn't matched as "active" when its descendant paths are matched." So yeah, a bit of an amalgamation of the old v5 `exact` *and* `strict` properties. Has my answer here resolved/helped you otherwise though?

Comment: It was mentioned in the [Upgrade from v5](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/upgrading/v5#change-the-order-of-arguments-passed-to-matchpath-change-pathpattern-options) documentation. but I agree with the sentiment that the upgrade from v5 is rather painful and full of surprises!